# What kind of templating are these html files in a VUE project?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  {{ partial:head }}
  <body class="font-sans antialiased">
    {{ yield:after_body }}
    <div id="main" @dragover.prevent @drop.prevent>
      <the-header 
        :transparent="Boolean({{ alternate_header }})"
        {{ if show_notice }}
          :notice="{text: '{{ notice | smartypants }}', target: '{{ notice_target }}', color: '{{ notice_color }}'}"
        {{ /if }}
      >
```

It is in a VUE project, that got compiled with laravel-mix and webpack.

I have  `/templates` `/layout` `/partials` folders containing HTML like this.

Comment: It's a nasty mix of server-side template engine (not sure if it's Blade) and Vue in-dom templates, which is especially bad because they use the same `{{` delimiter.

Comment: Was gonna say the same, looks like a mix between several things. Do you have some file like `login.blade.vue` extension or alike? Reminder me of ugly hacks in Ruby on Rails haha. Check that page for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#main-content Still, this is not common VueJS syntax for sure.

Comment: I don’t have any blade files. The whole project is a laravel statamic backend with a vue frontend. I’m not crazy versed in the server-side-templating part, but I now assume that the backend infrastructure somehow generates the templates for the Vue frontend-application which is bad since the end-goal is to decouple the frontend from the backend. I think the only way for me is to re-write this in Vue while at the same time making the data available through a new CMS.

Comment: Your thing is then compiling it afterwards somehow. And yeah, your backend app is responsible for the rendering of your Vue app, better to refacto it into a separate Vue + Laravel API.